# optional nullable DateTime value in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is my model :

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate {get;set; }
}
```

in my controller i want let the DateTime property value to be optional, in another word user can enter or not enter the value to this property. 
how can i do this ?
***EDIT*** :
DbContext class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
   public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

my action method :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonId,Name,BirthDate")] Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Persons.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges(); // error is thrown
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(person);
}
```

Exception(thrown when trying to create a record with null DateTime value):

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

inner exeptions:

```
Exception:Thrown: "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated."
Time: 07/14/2015 08:41:59 ب.ظ
Thread:Worker Thread[3028]

Exception:Caught: "Culture is not supported." (System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException)
A System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException was caught: "Culture is not supported."
Time: 07/14/2015 08:41:42 ب.ظ
Thread:<No Name>[8284]
```

**Note:**
right now i figured out that if i don't use custom binder and culture every thing works fine.

Comment: Isn't it already by virtue of being nullable and not having a `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: @Jamiec no, when BirthDate  is null it throws an exception on saveChanges() method.

Comment: Please post your code with `saveChanges()` It could be that wherever you are saving it in the db, the DB column is not nullable.

Comment: And the exception is.....? Point is, if you've gotten as far as trying to save the entity then the model binding must have worked with no value for `BirthDate`.

Comment: post your mapping class

Comment: You've still not told us what exception you're getting! Wall of code does not help.

Comment: You have not provided the `saveChanges()` method... No one asked to see your custom culture stuff... Please only post relevant code, not your whole sln.

Comment: @JamieRees there is no saveChanges() method.

Comment: @ReZa WHAT?! Look at your 2nd comment " it throws an exception on saveChanges() method. " Post the code where you are using it.

Comment: @JamieRees :) , i mean i use the base saveChanges() method.

Comment: Post the code where you are using it. If that's where the exception is getting thrown then we need to see it. If the `BirthDate` in the DB a nullable column?

Comment: See the bit that says `See the inner exception for details.` - did you think to follow the advice? (This is like pulling teeth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if this is right solution or not :
after changing data type from *datetime* to *datetime2*  in SQL Server 2014, it works.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException` indicates that the value is being passed to your controller just fine, but your data layer thinks that the value is required. Check your schema to ensure that this column is nullable.